# I have two files template.ps1 and config.ps1, I am trying to get the value of a parameter from template file and update it in config.ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I have tried using `get-content` method but not sure how to access the values of a variable

```
**Template.ps1 file**
$subscriptionID = "1234-x3nsfsf-sds-1234"
$serviicename = "sql"
$usernane = "testfromemplate"
$password = "**8888888*13"
$testvar2 = ""


**Config.ps1 file**

$subscriptionID = "67688-x3nsfsf-sds-wrongvalue"
$serviicename = "sql"
$usernane = ""
$password = "test123"
$otherconfig = "this is extra variable in config file"
$multipleotherconfigs = ""
```

I wanted to update the specific parameters from template file to config file is subscription , username and password

I am trying to get below output file:

```
**Output Config.ps1 file**

$subscriptionID = "1234-x3nsfsf-sds-1234"
$serviicename = "sql"
$usernane = "testfromemplate"
$password = "**8888888*13"
$otherconfig = "this is extra variable in config file"
$multipleotherconfigs = $env:config
```

I am able to get these values if i have saved them in json file bu these were in .ps1 files so unable to get these values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by first parsing out the values from the template.ps1 file and then use daisy-chained `-replace` actions on the content of the config.ps1 file.

Upon posting, I think you made a typo: `$usernane` --> `$username`, so below Im''m using the correct spelling:

```
# read the values you need from the Template.ps1 file
$subscriptionID = $username = $password = $null
switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\Template.ps1' {
    '^\$subscriptionID\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"' { $subscriptionID = $matches[1] }
    '^\$username\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"'       { $username = $matches[1] }
    '^\$password\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"'       { $password = $matches[1] }
}

# read the config file as one single, multiline string and do the replacements on it
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\Config.ps1' -Raw ) -replace 
    '(?m)^\$subscriptionID\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"', ('$subscriptionID = "{0}"' -f $subscriptionID) -replace
    '(?m)^\$username\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"', ('$username = "{0}"' -f $username) -replace
    '(?m)^\$password\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"', ('$password = "{0}"' -f $password) |
Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\Config.ps1'   # overwrite the config file with the new values.
```